# Can grunt watch remote files?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch

The title pretty much says it.

A little detail:
I use Joomla to build websites, usually I do it on my local computer and upload the whole website when I am done. But for some projects I need to directly modify `.js` `.css` files on the server in my day-to-day work. I just get to know `Grunt` and I'd like it to do some chores for me regarding those files like uglify or autoprefix. I read lots of articles and got to know that Grunt can watch local files so that whenenver they are changed it runs some tasks against them.

Since I am directly modifying files on server, can `Grunt` also watch those files? 
Alternatively, because I am using Fireftp, which allows me to download a temporary copy of the target file and whenever I make changes to and save the temporary file, it will be uploaded back and overrite the target file on server, is it possible to make grunt kick in and do the tasks before the file is uploaded back?

Answer (score 0):

The connect task run its own server to serve the static pages. And the livereload task refreshes the pages if any changes in the files that is mentioned in the `watch:livereload` task.

You don't need default static server. So go and remove connect task from Gruntfile

```
connect: {
    options: {
        port: 9000,
        // change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside
        hostname: 'localhost'
    },
    livereload: {
        options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                    lrSnippet,
                    mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                    mountFolder(connect, 'app')
                ];
            }
        }
    },
    test: {
        options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                    mountFolder(connect, '.tmp'),
                    mountFolder(connect, 'test')
                ];
            }
        }
    },
    dist: {
        options: {
            middleware: function (connect) {
                return [
                    mountFolder(connect, 'dist')
                ];
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Also remove `connect:livereload` and `open` from `server` task

```
grunt.task.run([
    'clean:server',
    'concurrent:server',
    'livereload-start',
    'connect:livereload',      // Remove This line
    'open',                    // Remove This line
    'watch'
]);
```

Then add following scripts in your html files.

```
<!-- livereload script -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script src="http://'
        + (location.host || 'localhost').split(':')[0]
        + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1" type="text/javascript"><\/script>')
</script>
```

Source: [Grunt Live reloading with external server](http://www.fizerkhan.com/blog/posts/Grunt-Live-reloading-with-external-server.html)

Another [interesting discussion](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/issues/203)